# OneDrive client authentication (SDK)

Tags: c#, authentication, sdk, onedrive

I'm playing with OneDrive SDK 1.1.15.0:

```
try
{
    AppConfig appConfig = new AppConfig
    {
        MicrosoftAccountAppId = oneDriveClientID, //something like 00000000123456AB
        MicrosoftAccountClientSecret = oneDriveClientSecret, //something like 3vx[...]1sJ
        MicrosoftAccountReturnUrl = "https://localhost/return",
        MicrosoftAccountScopes = new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.offline_access", "onedrive.readonly" }
    };
    OneDriveClient oneDriveClient = new OneDriveClient(appConfig);
    AccountSession accountSession = await oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();

    //more code

    await oneDriveClient.SignOutAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

My problem is in line:

```
AccountSession accountSession = await oneDriveClient.AuthenticateAsync();
```

that throws the following exception:

```
Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.OneDriveException, AuthenticationFailure: Failed to retrieve a valid authentication token for the user.
```

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**

After reading comment from ginach (thank you!), I update my code. Some arguments to underline:

- I want to access OneDrive from an Azure worker Role, so no authentication windows or something like that.
- I upload the Microsoft.OneDrive SDK to 1.1.20 version.
- I already registered my application to the OneDrive dev portal.

My actual code is:

```
try
{
    MicrosoftAccountServiceInfo serviceInfo = new MicrosoftAccountServiceInfo();

    serviceInfo.AppId = oneDriveClientID; //something like: 00000000ABCDEFGH
    serviceInfo.ClientSecret = oneDriveClientSecret; //something like: 3vx[...]1sJ
    serviceInfo.ReturnUrl = oneDriveReturnUrl; //something like: https://localhost/return
    serviceInfo.Scopes = oneDriveAccountScopes; //something like new string[] { "wl.signin", "wl.offline_access", "onedrive.readonly" }

    MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new MicrosoftAccountAuthenticationProvider(serviceInfo);

    OneDriveClient oneDriveClient = await OneDriveClient.GetAuthenticatedMicrosoftAccountClient(oneDriveClientID, oneDriveReturnUrl, oneDriveAccountScopes, authenticationProvider);

    //more code

    await oneDriveClient.SignOutAsync();
}
catch (OneDriveException odex)
{
    throw odex;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

I obtain again and again (in *OneDriveClient.GetAuthenticatedMicrosoftAccountClient* method) a OneDriveException stating (Error property): AuthenticationFailure - Failed to retrieve a valid authentication token for the user.

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

**UPDATE 2**

OK, I'm trying a new approach. Using RestSharp I try to login to OneDrive with that code:

```
string clientId = "00[...]00";
string scopes = "wl.signin, wl.offline_access, onedrive.readonly";
string responseType = "code";
string redirectUri = "https://login.live.com/oauth20_desktop.srf";

RestClient client = new RestClient("https://login.live.com");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest();

request.Method = Method.GET;
request.Resource = "oauth20_authorize.srf";
request.AddQueryParameter("client_id", clientId);
request.AddQueryParameter("scope", scopes);
request.AddQueryParameter("response_type", responseType);
request.AddQueryParameter("redirect_uri", redirectUri);

IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
string content = response.Content;
```

I check the request with Fiddler and what I'm sending is:

```
https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=00[...]00&scope=wl.signin%20wl.offline_access%20onedrive.readonly&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flogin.live.com%2Foauth20_desktop.srf
```

But OneDrive server answers my with:

*Microsoft account requires JavaScript to sign in. This web browser either does not support JavaScript, or scripts are being blocked. To find out whether your browser supports JavaScript, or to allow scripts, see the browser's online help.*

So I try the request in a browser and OneDrive server redirects me to the authorization page:

[image]

Now the question is: is there any workaround to skip the manual authorization?

Thank you,
Attilio

Answer (score 1):

The client requires an authentication provider to be able to retrieve authentication tokens. There are a few ways to do this depending on your current platform.

1. Create your own `IAuthenticationProvider` implementation. The authentication provider is responsible for setting the Authentication header on requests. Here's how you would create a client instance with a custom authentication provider:

> var client = new OneDriveClient(appConfig, serviceInfoProvider: new
>   ServiceInfoProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider()));

2. Use one of the various default authentication implementations. Take a look at the SDK [authentication documentation](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-csharp/blob/master/docs/auth.md) for the available options and examples.
3. If you have a refresh token and only want to do the silent authentication flow you can use `OneDriveClient.GetSilentlyAuthenticatedMicrosoftAccountClient`. Here's an example:

> var client = await OneDriveClient.GetSilentlyAuthenticatedMicrosoftAccountClient(clientId, returnUrl, scopes, refreshToken);

Comment: Hi. The Link of Auth  doc you refer is broken, could you update it? please ? or maybe do you have a sample ?